# How to create unique GPG Keys for different environments / projects

Tags: security, encryption, gpg

After searching and reading various documents it remains unclear to me as to an effective/straightforward manner to create/maintain multiple sets of GPG Keys.

I have a project that needs unique GPG Keys per environment and each user has their own GPG Key. Thus each server (environment) needs unique GPG keys.

I would envision the most secure and best practice is for each environment would have its own `gpg --gen-key` results for which to base its own private and public keys. From there an admin could add a user to each environment as needed.

Or am I just missing the point all together?

Comment: I'm not a GPG guru, but maybe you should look into `gpg subkeys`? You can have a `master` key and `sub` keys which are associated with the `master` one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the requirement is that "each user has their own gpg key", that seems like the typical use case for gpg. Can you elaborate a bit on what you want?

Comment: @larsks I have several environments (project A, dev, staging, production, project B, etc) that each are required to have their own GPG keys. My confusion is if I use my GPG key for my user to create a unique secret and public keys for each environment are each of these server deployments not dependent now upon my master key? Would it not be more appropriate to create a master key for each environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create separate key pairs that are not dependent on your personal keys, the easiest way is to use a separate GPG home directory for each. For example, to create keys for "projectB", first create an empty directory, then tell gpg to use that dir as its home:

```
mkdir projectB-gpg
gpg --homedir ./projectB-gpg --gen-key
```

That will do what you want, although you will now have the problem of distributing the private keys and passwords securely to each environment.